# ElasticSearch queries always return all the datas stored in the index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to index and query an index store in ES 1.2. I both create and populate  the index with the JAVA API using the transportclient api. I have the following mapping

```
get /tp/carte/_mapping
{
   "tp": {
      "mappings": {
         "carte": {
            "properties": {
               "adherents": {
                  "properties": {
                     "birthday": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                     },
                     "firstname": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "lastname": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "dateEdition": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I search ob object with the ID, it works fine but, when I try to query the content of one of my nested objects, **ES always returns all the objects stored in the index**.
I also tried to create the objects manually with sense and I have the same behaviour.

Example of my insert

```
post /tp/carte/20454795
{
               "dateEdition": "2014-06-01T22:00:00.000Z",
               "adherents": [
                  {
                     "birthday": "1958-05-05T23:00:00.000Z",
                     "firstname": "ANDREW",
                     "lastname": "DOE"
                  },
                  {
                     "birthday": "1964-03-01T23:00:00.000Z",
                     "firstname": "ROBERT",
                     "lastname": "DOE"
                  },
                  {
                     "birthday": "1989-02-27T23:00:00.000Z",
                     "firstname": "DAVID",
                     "lastname": "DOE"
                  },
                  {
                     "birthday": "1990-12-11T23:00:00.000Z",
                     "firstname": "JOHN",
                     "lastname": "DOE"
                  }
               ]
            }
```

Finally, you could find below a query executed in sense

```
get /tp/carte/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [        
        {
          "match": {
            "adherents.lastname": {
              "query": "DOE"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

How can I fix that ?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The search queries was executed by a GET request. The content is always ignored. with a POST the query's return is good

Comment: How were you executing the queries? That depends on the language/library as in some cases they don't support a request body with GET.